# Firestore Rules - Datatype Validation

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I've read multiple questions in Stack Overflow and the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/) but I couldn't find multiple validations that I can imagine that exist.

Per example, it is possible to check `if request.resource.data.description is string` but can is it possible to do the same when it comes to `number`, `float`, `timestamp` or even `array`/`list`? I couldn't even find the `string` one in the documentation so I can imagine it is missing more than just that one.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You might want to watch my [video on data types in Firebase security rules](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qbd_4LT0Y4s).  In it, I list all the different data types that you can check:

```
value is bool
value is int
value is float
value is number
value is string

value is list
value is map

value is timestamp
value is duration
value is path
value is latlng
```

Comment: Thank you Doug, that was exactly what I was looking for and that I couldn't find anywhere in the documentation!

Comment: Yeah, the documentation is going through improvements, for sure.

Comment: Just what I was looking for!

Comment: According to an error message I just got the full list is: bool,bytes,constraint,duration,float,int,latlng,list,set,number,map,string,timestamp,path,map_diff