# Security rules for cloud firestore (CEL)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, common-expression-language

guys, can any one tell me in security rules for cloud firestore where i can see all methods to validate data using common expression language(CEL) like (hasOnly(),hasAll(),isNumber)

common expression language methods or functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a list of all objects, classes and properties in the [reference documentation of Firestore security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/index-all).

There is no `isNumber` function there though. As far as I know that is only defined for security rules of the Realtime Database (see [`isNumber`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database#isnumber)), which uses a different language.

Comment: hii Frank thanks for information. Can you tell me how to implement these properties of data validation like type checking and size

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/data-validation#firestore and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58032110/firestore-rules-datatype-validation